# Having difficulty navigating webpages using rvest package

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am having real difficulty with the rvest package in R. I am trying to navigate to a particular webpage after hitting an "I Agree" button on the first webpage. Here's [the link](http://wonder.cdc.gov/mcd-icd10.html) to the webpage that I begin with. The code below attempts to obtain the next webpage which has a form to fill out in order to obtain data that I will need to extract.

```
url <- "http://wonder.cdc.gov/mcd-icd10.html"
pgsession <- html_session(url)
pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[3]]
new_session <- html_session(submit_form(pgsession,pgform)$url)
pgform_new <- html_form(new_session)
```

The last line does not obtain the html form for the next webpage and gives me the following error in R.

```
Error in read_xml.response(x$response, ..., as_html = as_html) : 
server error: (500) Internal Server Error
```

Would very much appreciate any help that I can get with this in both getting to the next webpage and also submitting a form to obtain data. Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Unwrap your call; `submit_form` is failing because it can't find the submit button.

Comment: Trying this gets you one step closer: `submit_form(pgsession, pgform, submit="action-I Agree")` but when trying to jump_to the next page stills generates an error.

Comment: @Dave2e worked for me